# what will be uri for Sqlite database which is in SDCARD in CursorLoader

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager, android-cursorloader

I am new to android and i have read so many things for best way to load data from an Sqlitedatabase, and from reading blog of Alex Lockwood.  I finally decided to go with CursorLoader & LoaderManager.

My problem is that many people want to read data without ContentProvider [CursorLoader usage without ContentProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182485/usage-cursorloader-without-contentprovider?lq=1) do not know why they don't want to use ContentProvider can any body suggest me?

If contentprovider is best solution than i just want to make URI for external database.  Please, any body know how to make external database which is reside in sdcard?  I want to fetch uri of that database or if i put my database in /data/data/packagename/databases/ then how can i fetch it?  Please, any body know than suggest me.

Answer (score -1):

Kinjal may be You don't need a provider to use an SQLite database if the use is entirely within your own application.

it suggest in android developer site just chk it http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to use a CursorLoader without a ContentProvider.